# Which attributes to release and which not?

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsstring, interface-builder

In my app I define some attributes in my h file.

As far as I understand, if there is an attributes that gets "alloc" someplace in the m file, I should release it in the dealloc method (or before if it's not relevant anymore).

I'm not clear about attributes that don't get "alloc":

- **NSString** - should I release them (I read posts that say "yes" and posts that say "no")
- **NSDictionary / NSArray**  - when I create them I don't use "alloc", but some arrayWith or dictionaryWith methods; do they get memory allocation that require releasing or can I assume that XCode is taking care of their data management?
- **BOOL** - just want to verify that I don't need to release them
- **int** - just want to verify that I don't need to release them
- **UI items** (like UIButton, UILabel, etc...) - these items are connected in IB, I don't have an "alloc" from within the code - is IB releasing them or am I supposed to do it myself?
- How does the attribute being **Propertied** affects the memory management requirements? copy / retain / assign / nonatomic (I understand that when I do "copy" I'm creating another copy and therefore supposably allocation more memory, but I saw example codes that in some cases release copied propertied attributes and in some cases not)

I don't mind reading another tutorial (in most cases when I ask a question about Memory Management, I get people sending me the link to the Apple Memory Management Guide), but if someone can explain it or can direct to a more vivide/clear tutorial than the one Apple presents I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`@"some string"` is `autoreleased`. Don't worry about these. When you pass it to an object, like `viewController.title = @"some string";` the string will be retained and managed by the other object.

There are two ways to create `NSSet`s, `NSArray`s or `NSDictionary`s.
You can either use `alloc` and `init` and have to `release` it later on, or use the `+arrayWith...` methods which return an `autoreleased` object.

Don't worry about primitive data types like `BOOL`s or `int`s.

Properties which `retain` the value are **strong** properties, basically they make sure that the objects stays in memory until they `release` it again. You mostly use `retain` for any kind of object, watch out for [retain cycles](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html) though!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of answers out there for this question, as you say you have read the memory management tutorials, but I guess what you are looking for is a nice example to get it clear in your head.

The most helpful explanation on Cocoa memory management I read was in the Hillegass book (Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X), where he described an object as like a dog. Every time you use one of the methods that increases the retain count (`new`, `copy`,`retain`,`init` a few I've bound to have forgotten, these are in the memory management guide you've already read) then **you are putting another lead on the dog's neck**.

I will now take this perfectly good metaphor to silly extremes. You asked for a vivid example!

- You have to take any of *your* leads off the dog once you are done with it. Otherwise you'll drive off with it tied to your car like on National Lampoon's Vacation, which isn't nice - this is a **memory leak**.
- If you don't have a lead on the dog, you can't guarantee it will be there when you want it to do a trick. This could be **sending a message to a released object**.
- If you go to take your lead off the dog, and there are no leads on it, then the dog could horribly savage you as you **over-release** it.

So, in essence, if you've put a lead on the dog, you have to take it off. If you haven't (i.e. you havent called `new` or `retain` etc) then you don't. This applies to all objects. `BOOL` and `int` are not objects so you don't have to worry about them.

*No dogs are harmed during my day to day programming activities*